# VBA Error 4605 This method or property is not available because the document is in modal state

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

Environment: Word 2016 for Mac.

The following code (which works fine in Word 2007 and 2010 for PC and Word 2011 for Mac) throws run time error 4605 at the point of the paste:

```
Set oSubRange = wdDoc.Sections(i).Range ' we are in a loop...            
oSubRange.End = oSubRange.End - 1 
oSubRange.Copy
Set wdSubDoc = Documents.Add
wdSubDoc.Activate
Set oRange = wdSubDoc.Content
oRange.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
oRange.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

My thoughts were that maybe this was a sandboxing problem, but I don't think so because I have had no issues with saving files, and this is not at the point of save anyhow.  Other thoughts were that the clipboard was not copying, that perhaps there was a timing issue.  I tried inserting a DoEvents() after the copy as I have seen this suggested in different error 4605 scenarios (different error though).  Also tried using ActiveDocument.Range.PasteAndFormant(wdFormatOriginalFormatting) which was suggested in another forum by a MS MVP (again, different error 4605). None of these solutions worked.

So, I am stuck.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should try it again in the latest version 16.9 which came out last week. This was a major update.

Comment: I found a solution.  I made the forms/dialog boxes I was using for data input non-modal via the form properties in the VBA IDE. Why MS requires this now escapes me, but at least there is a solution.